# shell script to check accuracy of the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have script which check the accuracy of how many buckets were removed. I want a script to write which help me once the above script stop running, it has to check the file again and there are any left buckets creates an input list and runs a second "rm -rf" on the rest of them then repeats itself until they are all gone.
please find the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /tmp/buckets_to_remove/*

# Ensure that the /tmp/buckets_to_remove directory exists and if not then create it
if [ ! -d /tmp/buckets_to_remove ]
 then
  mkdir /tmp/buckets_to_remove
fi

please find the error below:
Removing bucket act/1473823073_1459448859_XXXXX
Removing bucket act/1453904759_1438082433_XXXXX
Removing bucket act/1477122647_1442503432_XXXXX
Removing bucket asa/1473740503_1472875269_XXXXX
Removing bucket asa/1473741465_1473740502_XXXXX
Removing bucket asa/1473740504_1473740502_XXXXX
```

Comment: `rm /tmp/buckets_to_remove/*` will remove the contents, not the folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

The `rm` command will run continuously every 15 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ensure that the /tmp/buckets_to_remove directory exists and if not then create it
if [ ! -d /tmp/buckets_to_remove ]
    then
    mkdir /tmp/buckets_to_remove
fi

while(true)
    do
        for rmbuckets in $( ( ls /tmp/buckets_to_remove/ ) )
        do
            rm "$rmbuckets"
        done
    sleep 15
    done
```

Comment: didn't this solution help?